# How to make Reverse polish notation in Scala with Recursion?

Tags: algorithm, scala, tree

I tried to make RPN in scala but i got Exception in console

> Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: 1 (of class
>   java.lang.Character)

and i stop here because Intelij don't show where is problem . I think that i 'am wrong making

```
if (!expr.isEmpty) {
  expr.head match
```

but i spend some hours thinking how to exchange this and i din't invent anything

i make this program in Java but in functional programming i don't know how to  correctly use this match with tail Recursive

```
object RPN extends App {

  print(evaluate("123++"))
 def evaluate( expr : String)  {
   val stack =  Stack[Double]()

   var  a,b  :Int=0
   @tailrec
def helper ( asset : String){

if (!expr.isEmpty) {
  expr.head match {
    case it if 0 until 9 contains it => stack.push(expr.head); helper(asset.tail)
    case '+' => b = stack.pop.toString().toInt; a = stack.pop.toString().toInt; stack.push(a + b)
    case '-' => b = stack.pop.toString().toInt; a = stack.pop.toString().toInt; stack.push(a - b)
    case '*' => b = stack.pop.toString().toInt; a = stack.pop.toString().toInt; stack.push(a * b)
    case '/' => b = stack.pop.toString().toInt; a = stack.pop.toString().toInt; stack.push(a / b)
  }
}
else return stack.pop
    }
   helper(expr)

}
}
```

Comment: You probably want `if (!asset.isEmpty) {  asset.head match`, not `expr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is referencing `expr` inside of `helper()`, where you probably want to reference `asset` instead.

Also, you don't need the `return` or the `var`s.

```
def evaluate(expr :String) :Double = {
  val stack = collection.mutable.Stack[Double]()

  @annotation.tailrec
  def helper(asset :String) :Double =
    if (asset.isEmpty) stack.pop
    else {
      asset.head match {
        case c if c.isDigit => 
                    stack.push(c.asDigit)
        case '+' => stack.push(stack.pop + stack.pop)
        case '-' => stack.push(-stack.pop + stack.pop)
        case '*' => stack.push(stack.pop * stack.pop)
        case '/' => stack.push(1/stack.pop * stack.pop)
        case  c  => throw new Error(s"Bad Char: $c")
      }
      helper(asset.tail)
    }

  helper(expr)
}
```

testing:

```
evaluate("123++")  //res0: Double = 6.0
evaluate("954--")  //res1: Double = 8.0
evaluate("423*+")  //res2: Double = 10.0
evaluate("28/")    //res3: Double = 0.25
evaluate("73/")    //res4: Double = 2.333333333333333
```

Comment: why you use "@annotation.tailrec" instead of "@tailrec" ? and you are right with asset, is any better possible solution of checking when asset is empty ? But your improving of this is very attractive and clear

Comment: I use `@annotation.tailrec` in example code just to reduce the number of `import`s required. Many people post incomplete code because they forget to include the necessary imports. I try to avoid that.